# What's the difference between pictureBox.Update() and pictureBox.Refresh()

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

New to programming and English is not my first language. I am having a hard time trying to understand the difference of `Control.Update()` and `Control.Refresh()` the MSDN documentation.

I am trying to display real time image to the picturebox, but i dont know which method to use will be best. Like, in what kind of situation should i use `Control.Update()` over `Control.Refresh`, or do i use both of them?

P.s if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh( ) calls Invalidate(true) to invalidate the control and its children and then calls Update( ) to force paint the control so that the invalidation is synchronous.

More details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/subhagpo/2005/02/22/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh/).

In short:

- Calling the Invalidate() method does not force a **synchronous** paint;
- to force a synchronous paint, call the **Update** method after calling
  the Invalidate method.
- Calling refresh() does both Invalidate() + Update()

Comment: ya i read that but i got confused. So basically all i need to do is just use Refresh() and then ignore the Update(). Since by using Refresh(), it will invalidate the control and then automatically call Update()?

Comment: @Jarad Well most of the time you just call `Invalidate()`.  The others hurt performance too much